# How to do change of static variables in a singleton in a threadsafe way?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a singleton class with multiple static variables and a refresh method to change their values. eg.

```
Class Singleton {

@Getter(AccessLevel.Protected)
private static Immutable vara;

@Getter(AccessLevel.Protected)
private static Immutable varb;

@Getter(AccessLevel.Protected)
private static Immutable varc;

public void refresh() {
//refreshes the values of vara, varb, varc;
}
```

This singleton class is accessed in a service class where the variables are accessed.
How can I make the process of refresh thread safe so that refresh doesn't happen between two accesses? eg.
--->access vara ---> refresh ---> access varb.
My app is deployed on tomcat.

UPDATE: As recommended in the comments, I have modified the class to contain all the three reference variables in a single container class and made them immutable. Now I intend on simply updating the reference to the object in main class using refresh. Is it sufficient to use volatile for the object in the Singleton class for the container class or is an explicit AtomicReference required?
New class:

```
Class Singleton {
private Container container;//contains immutable invariants

public Container getContainer() {
    return this.container;
}
void init() {
// sets initial values for the container object
}
public void refresh() {
// updates the container reference
}
```

Comment: What does a `refresh()` entail?

Comment: The architecture overall has some downsides. The class provided is not really a singleton, but a utility-class, only providing `static` methods. The fact that the static fields are not `final` indicate that `vara`, `varb` and `varc` are not singletons either.

Comment: The direct approach without architecture changes: add a `ReadWriteLock`/`StampedLock` for these. With design changes, you could maintain a container for these references, and swap the _entire_ container in one operation with the new values. Remember that `static` is typically a tool for memory/optimization, not for interface management / simplicity of access.

Comment: If it only has static variables why is it a singleton at all? You don't need to instantiate it.

Comment: @Turing85 In refresh I am constructing Container Object through a Builder and assigning the created object to Container reference variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I intend on simply updating the reference to the object in main class using refresh. Is it sufficient to use volatile for the object in the Singleton class for the container class or is an explicit AtomicReference required?

Good idea to put the fields into a single wrapper immutable object.  Then each thread with see a fully constructed wrapper object.  The race condition however is that they may see the previous wrapper object or the newly refreshed wrapper.  If each thread *must* see the most updated version then you should use `AtomicReference` or just make the `static Wrapper` field be `volatile` so that any updates are published immediately and any access to the wrapper sees the most recently refreshed version.  Typically the cost of the `volatile` memory barrier is low enough that it won't be detectable.  Be careful of premature optimization.

However, you can also allow lazy refreshing to happen if that is appropriate to your application.  If your threads cross other memory barriers or if they have cache update hardware then they will get the new wrapper object at some point just no guarantees about how fast.  This may be required if this wrapper object is referenced often by the threads.

So if it is critical logic then pay for the `AtomicReference` but if it is informational or something that is accessed super often then a lazy update may be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Gray. As you suggested, I have used the AtomicReference to publish the object and ensure visibility guarantee.

Answer (score 2):

Protecting `static` variables is no different from protecting any other variables. Use `synchronized` blocks when accessing them.  Normally you would `synchronize` on a `final` lock object that is declared in the same scope, and with the same extent as the variables that you are trying to protect. E.g.;

```java
static FooType foo;
static BarType bar;
static BazType baz;

// Only access foo, bar, and baz from within synchronized(lock) {...}.
final static Object lock = new Object();
```

If you're doing some kind of sophisticated trickery* where `synchronized` doesn't work for you, then you may need to up the ante, and use a [`ReentrantLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html).

---

*But of course, if you were planning anything so sophisticated, then you probably would not be asking your question here.

Comment: Good answer. It might also be worth clarifying that the lock needs to be acquired by the getter methods in order to be thread safe, and that means that the original code’s use of annotations to auto-generate getters will need to change to explicitly-written getters.